# import an excel file with PHP Excel Reader

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this class to import a large amount of data. Most of the data is being read correctly, however I have two date columns which are giving me problems.

The dates are in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` and the values returned are one day ahead of those in the spreadsheet. For example, `04/03/2011 00:00` becomes `04/03/2011 02:00`

I have tried accessing the data like this:

```
$data->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$row][$col];
```

I have also tried using the raw data:

```
$data->sheets[$sheet]['cellsInfo'][$row][$col]['raw']
```

Which returns the date as a unix timestamp but still it is one day ahead of what it should be.

Is there any way I can force the class to return the value of the column as a simple string?

Comment: And where does this class come from? Provide a link? There may be many different products by this name.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the right row/col?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.  Linke to PHPExcel reader:
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

I suspect something with the way Excel is recording the date.  The spreadsheet is generated in USA and IT operations are in Australia (where I am), not sure if that is relevant

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple - why don't you just deduct a day from the timestamp, or from the date you fetch?

```php
$wrongDateTimestamp = "1304398800"; 

$rightDateTimestamp = strtotime("-1 day", $wrongDateTimeStamp); // Or alternatively - $wrongDateTimeStam - 86400
$rightDate = date("d/m/Y", $rightDateTimestamp);
```

Hope this helps.
Shai.

Comment: While this "works", I think understanding why all dates are recording as a day ahead (or a day less as it were in Excel) would be better as if it is not consistantly out by a day you are changing the outcome of the process